# Android studio architecture

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, mvvm

Hi im currently working with android studio. I have coded my project but i didnt realise until i was finished that i didnt follow MVC or MVVM. I dont understand how to implement these design patterns, would anyone please be able to give me some guidance on how to build and implement this structure.

I have looked at tutorials and documentation but i can really get my head around any of it. I just need to implement whichever is easier. Sorry if i have not formulated my question the best, im still quite new here.

Thanks

Comment: I would start with Android Developer's recommended practices: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.